# How to calculate R Squared value for Lasso regression using glmnet in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am performing lasso regression in R using glmnet package:

```
fit.lasso <- glmnet(x,y)
plot(fit.lasso,xvar="lambda",label=TRUE)
```

[image: fit.lasso plot]

Then using cross-validation:

```
cv.lasso=cv.glmnet(x,y)
plot(cv.lasso)
```

[image: lambda VS MSE]

[One tutorial](http://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/7600/s16/notes/2-22.pdf) (last slide) suggest the following for R^2:

```
R_Squared =  1 - cv.lasso$cvm/var(y)
```

But it did not work.

I want to understand the model efficiency/performance in fitting the data. As we usually get R^2 and adjusted R^2 when performing lm() function in r.

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? This does produce an answer. Do you think the answer is wrong for some reason?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using "gaussian" family, you can access R-squared value by

fit.lasso$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio

Comment: From glmnet documentation, dev.ratio is `The fraction of (null) deviance explained (for "elnet", this is the R-square).`

Comment: This is a highly misleading answer, though, as it does not adjust for overfitting. R-squared should be calculated based on the cross-validated deviance ratio.

Answer (score 2):

## I use the example data to demonstrate it

library(glmnet)

#### load data

```
data(BinomialExample)
head(x) 
head(y)
```

#### For cross validation

```
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", type.measure = "class")
rsq = 1 - cvfit$cvm/var(y)
plot(cvfit$lambda,rsq)
```

[image]

Comment: you provided an example with a classification problem, OP is working on a regression problem

Answer (score 0):

#### Firtst fit the Lasso model with the selected lambda

...

`lasso.model <- glmnet(x=X,y=Y,  family = "binomial",  alpha=1,  lambda = cv.model$lambda.min )`

### then you could get the pseudo  R2 from the fitted model

```
`lasso.model$dev.ratio`
```

this value give the deviance explained by the model/Null deviance

Comment: Don't do this, you don't want to refit the glmnet based on cv.model. There is literally already a cv.model$glmnet.fit which mirrors the cv.model exactly.
It looks like Woodstock is doing it correctly.